# In python, is there anyway to input a string without quotation marks?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I want user to input a name of a table, `table = str(input("table: "))` works, but it's kind of annoying to put `'name'` everytime instead of just `name`, is there any work around for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `raw_input`:

```
table = raw_input("table: ")

>input([prompt])
```

Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`

This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.

If the readline module was loaded, then `input()` will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.

Consider using the `raw_input()` function for general input from users.

Comment: Note raw_input() disappeared with Python3